# How to describe type that ensures specific property on nested objects

Tags: typescript

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to check that property `a` exists in every object of hierarchy

```
{
  a: string
  key1: {
   a: string
   subkey1: {
    a: string
    k: number
   }
  }
 }
```

I tried several approaches like  `[key: string]: ContainsA | any;` but it`s too weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, but you'll need to make the type definition recursive:

```
interface ContainsA { 
    a: string;
    [key: string]:
        // Add any other leaf types that aren't required to contain `a` here.
        | string  // `a` itself
        | number  // `k`
        | ContainsA;
}
```

Comment: so I'll have to list all the types including array types. it feels like I can miss something. is it a better way?

Comment: If you forget a type in the list, you'll just get errors on the affected object literals until you add the type to the list.  It doesn't seem like a big problem to me.  If you need more help, please add more examples to the question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: ok. I also came up to this solution intially, but it filled a bit strange for me. but since also don't have a serious doubts about this, I think it's a way to go. thanks!